# Populate input field with checkboxes jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to populate two text fields with checkbox values. It will get the min and max data attribute values from the checkboxes, find the highest and lowest numbers, and set input fields with this values. If all checkboxes are unchecked, default values will be set.

For example if 50-100 and 200-300 options are checked, min input will be set to 50 and max input field will be set to 300

```
var lowest = +Infinity;
var highest = -Infinity;

 $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).filter(':checked').length > 0) {
        lowest = Math.min(lowest, parseFloat($(this).attr("data-min")));
        highest = Math.max(highest, parseFloat($(this).attr("data-max")));
        $("#price-min").val(lowest);
        $("#price-max").val(highest);
    } else {
        $("#price-min").val(1);
        $("#price-max").val(150000);
    }
});
```

here is my html :

```
<input id="price-min" type="text" value="0">
<input id="price-max" type="text" value="0"><br><br>
<input type="checkbox" data-min="50" data-max="100">50-100<br>
<input type="checkbox" data-min="100" data-max="200">100-200<br>
<input type="checkbox" data-min="200" data-max="300">200-300
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fpooysad/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the change event of `:checkbox` take all checked `min` and `max` value in two array using `map()` method and then sort these two array using `sort()`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="price-min" type="text" value="0">
<input id="price-max" type="text" value="0">
<br>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" data-min="50" data-max="100">50-100
<br>
<input type="checkbox" data-min="100" data-max="200">100-200
<br>
<input type="checkbox" data-min="200" data-max="300">200-300


<script>
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
        var min = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () { return $(this).data('min') }).get().sort(function (a, b) { return a - b });
        var max = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () { return $(this).data('max') }).get().sort(function (a, b) { return b - a });

        if (min.length) {
            $("#price-min").val(min[0]);
            $("#price-max").val(max[0]);
        } else {
            $("#price-min").val(1);
            $("#price-max").val(150000);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function () {
        var allChecked = $("input[type='checkbox']").filter(':checked');
        if (allChecked.length > 0) {
            var lowest = null;
            var highest = null;
            allChecked.each(function() {
                var low = parseFloat($(this).attr("data-min"));
                var high = parseFloat($(this).attr("data-max"));
                if (lowest == null || low < lowest) {
                    lowest = low;
                }
                if (highest == null || high > highest) {
                    highest = high;
                }
            });
            $("#price-min").val(lowest);
            $("#price-max").val(highest);
        } else {
            $("#price-min").val(1);
            $("#price-max").val(150000);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    var maxArr = [], minArr = [];
    var getMax = 15000, getMin = 0;
    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
        var getIndMax = $(this).attr("data-max");
      var getIndMin = $(this).attr("data-min");
      maxArr.push(getIndMax);
      minArr.push(getIndMin);
    });
    if(minArr.length) {
        getMin = Math.min.apply(null, minArr);
    }
    if(maxArr.length) {
        getMax = Math.max.apply(null, maxArr);
    }
    $("#price-min").val(getMin);
    $("#price-max").val(getMax);
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fpooysad/2/

**Terms Utilized**

`.push` is used in order to add a value in an array, in this case array vars are `maxArr` and `minArr`

`Math.min` & `.max` is to consider max and minimum values within an array

Answer (score -1):

This must help you out

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
  var lowest =+Infinity;
  var highest = 0;
    $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"),function(){
      lowest = parseInt($(this).data("min")) < lowest ?parseInt($(this).data("min")) : lowest;
      highest = parseInt($(this).data("max")) > highest ?parseInt($(this).data("max")) : highest;  
    });
    
    if (lowest ==0 && highest ==0) {
     $("#price-min").val(1);
      $("#price-max").val(150000);    
    } else {
       $("#price-min").val(lowest);
     $("#price-max").val(highest);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="price-min" type="text" value="0">
<input id="price-max" type="text" value="0">
<br>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" data-min="50" data-max="100">50-100
<br>
<input type="checkbox" data-min="100" data-max="200">100-200
<br>
<input type="checkbox" data-min="200" data-max="300">200-300
```

And here is [Working JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/fpooysad/3/)

Comment: Downvoters, please care to comment. Let me improve if there is a mistake, The snippet is working fine, The fiddle is working fine. Whats the problem?